# Compare three arrays of hashes and get the result without duplicates in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, hash, fql.multiquery

I m using the `fql gem` to retrieve the data from facebook. The original array of hashes is like this. [Here](http://pastie.org/9346738#279). When i compare these three arrays of hashes then i want to get the final result in this way:

```
{
      "photo" => [
        [0] {
                   "owner" : "1105762436",
                 "src_big" : "https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xap1/t31.0-8/q71/s720x720/10273283_10203050474118531_5420466436365792507_o.jpg",
                 "caption" : "Rings...!!\n\nView Full Screen.",
                 "created" : 1398953040,
                "modified" : 1398953354,
               "like_info" : {
                  "can_like" : true,
                "like_count" : 22,
                "user_likes" : true
            },
            "comment_info" : {
                  "can_comment" : true,
                "comment_count" : 2,
                "comment_order" : "chronological"
            },
               "object_id" : "10203050474118531",
                     "pid" : "4749213500839034982"
        }
    ],
    "comment" => [
        [0] {
                 "text" : "Wow",
            "text_tags" : [],
                 "time" : 1398972853,
                "likes" : 1,
               "fromid" : "100001012753267",
            "object_id" : "10203050474118531"
        },
        [1] {
                 "text" : "Woww..",
            "text_tags" : [],
                 "time" : 1399059923,
                "likes" : 0,
               "fromid" : "100003167704574",
            "object_id" : "10203050474118531"
        }
    ],
     "users" =>[
         [0] {
                  "id": "1105762436",
                "name": "Nilanjan Joshi",
            "username": "NilaNJan219"
         },
         [1] {
                  "id": "1105762436",
                "name": "Ashish Joshi",
            "username": "NilaNJan219"
         }
    ]
}
```

Here is my attempt:

```
datas = File.read('source2.json')
all_data = JSON.parse(datas)
photos = all_data[0]['fql_result_set'].group_by{|x| x['object_id']}.to_a 
comments = all_data[1]['fql_result_set'].group_by{|x| x['object_id']}.to_a 
@photos_comments = []
@comments_users = []
@photo_users = []
photos.each do |a|
 comments.each do |b|
   if a.first == b.first
    @photos_comments << {'photo' => a.last, 'comment' => b.last}   
   else
    @comments_users << {'photo' => a.last, 'comment' => ''} unless @photos_comments.include? (a.last)
   end
 end
end

@photo_users = @photos_comments | @comments_users
@photo_comment_users = {photos_comments: @photo_users }
```

Here is what i'm getting [final result](http://pastie.org/9346792)

Still there are duplicates in the final array. I've `grouped by` the array by `object id` which is common between the photo and the comment array. But the problem it is only taking those photos which has comments. I'm not getting the way how to find out the photos which don't have the comments.
Also in order to find out the details of the person who has commented, ive users array and the common attribute between `comments` and `users` is `fromid` and `id`. I'm not able to understand how to get the user details also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
photos = all_data[0]['fql_result_set']
comments = all_data[1]['fql_result_set'].group_by{|x| x['object_id']}
@photo_comment_users = photos.map do |p| 
  { 'photo' => p, 'comment' => comments[p['object_id']] || '' }
end
```

For each `photo` it takes all the `comments` with the same `object_id`, or if none exist - returns `''`.

---

If you want to connect the users too, you can map them by id, and select the relevant ones by the comment:

```
users = Hash[all_data[2]['fql_result_set'].map {|x| [x['id'], x]}]
@photo_comment_users = photos.map do |p| 
  { 'photo' => p, 'comment' => comments[p['object_id']] || '', 
    'user' => (comments[p['object_id']] || []).map {|c| users[c['formid']]} }
end
```

Comment: wow.. this works like a charm. Now i'm not missing any photo. But another part which i'm missing is how to iterate with the users array.

Comment: what's in the users array? how does it connect to the photos and comments?

Comment: Actually the users array connects with the comments array with the `fromid` which has the same value as the `id` in the users array.
see this http://pastie.org/9346738#279 
Refer to the third array.

Comment: @ahmadhamza - and where do you want to put it?

Comment: in the same array @photo_comments_users.

Comment: @ahmadhamza you want a list of all users who are connected to any comment on the photo?

Comment: i want a list of all users who has commented in a particular photo. So that i can show the photograph of the person who has commented out in front of his comment.